# Did Orochimaru release all the souls sealed inside Shinigami?

Tags: naruto

Orochimaru released the four previous Hokages from the Shinigami's stomach. Were there only four souls sealed inside its stomach? Or could the user choose to release only specific souls?

Answer (score 3):

The Shiki Fuujin was invented by Minato, and taught to Hiruzen. That was said during Hiruzen's battle with Orochimaru.

It was only ever used two times, once when sealing the Kyuubi (which caused himself to be sealed in the Shinigami), and once against Orochimaru by Hiruzen (which caused Hashirama, Tobirama, Hiruzen and Orochimaru's hands to be sealed).

Because of that, no other souls were sealed in the Shinigami's stomach.

---

True enough, the author later contradicted what he said at the beginning of the series, and said the the Shiki Fuujin was invented by the Uzumaki clan, and taught to Minato (probably by Kushina).

In that case, it may be possible to only unseal the specific souls you want to.

Comment: i thought this sealing jutsu belonged to the uzumakis who were the masters of sealing jutsus..

Comment: @debal is right. http://www.onemanga.me/naruto_manga/619/4/

Comment: This part: *The Shiki Fuujin was invented by Minato, and taught to Hiruzen.* lacks substantial reference. Specially the 'invented' part.

Comment: I have corrected my answer.

Comment: It can also be that The sealing jutsu was never used earlier because of the extreme price they have to pay for using it. The uzumakis had a wider range of seals to chose from... and maybe that Minato was infact the first person to ever use the jutsu. However this too lacks substantial proof.. so its just speculations.

Comment: also while watching the episode, a thought crossed my mind, what if there are multiple death gods or shinigami and for each there is a separate mask, as seen in the Uzumaki shrine.. and since orochimaru chose from a list of  many, he may have chosen the one that was used to seal him.. as he had seen the face of the death god that was summoned to seal him.His main objective was to release the first and hokage and he knew that they were sealing by the same death god that sealed his arms. Maybe the release of the 4th was an added bonus.

Comment: During Uzumaki clan massacre, they would've got many chances to use it against powerful enemies inorder to save their clan. More speculations :)

Comment: @MadaraUchiha The sealing Jutsu  (Shiki Fuujinwas) was NOT invented my Minato, It is the specialty of the Uzumaki clan and since Minato married Kushina. I'd actually say Kushina taught it to Minato and then maybe Minato showed Hiruzen. Also, a ritual is needed to collect the souls that are already within the Death Reaper. Someone would need to be possesed by the Shinigami and then act as a vessel to draw out the souls that they want to